# $filter('date') returning "invalid date"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a date string formatted like this:

```
20150917
```

I want to convert it to the format

```
17-sep-2015
```

So I am using this code to first convert the former to a date object and then convert it back to a string with the new format:

```
var myDate = $filter('date')(new Date(dateStr, 'yyyyMMdd'));
console.log(myDate); //to make sure
```

that console.log is giving me

```
Invalid Date
```

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
var dateString = "20150917";
$scope.myDate =  $filter('date')(new Date(dateString.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2-$3')), 'dd-MMM-yyyy');
console.log('$scope.myDate: ', $scope.myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see [moment](http://momentjs.com/) library.

You can test this:

```
moment(20150917).format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
```